# UIRefreshControl not working inside Container View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I've got ViewController, that has ContainerView with another ViewController and UITableView.

I am adding `UIRefreshControl` to tableView (inside Container) like this:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SomeViewController.reloadData), for: .valueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

And it does not work. `SomeViewController.reloadData` is never called. Now when I do the same thing, except without container, everything works.

Should I set some delegates or something to main/top ViewController, that has Container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `refreshControl` to the corresponding property on your `tableView` **instead** of adding it as a subview?

`tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

That should do it.

**edit:** If you support any iOS earlier than 10, you will not be able to add it to the `tableView` directly but will instead need to add it to your `UITableViewController`, assuming you are using one.

`self.refreshControl = refreshControl`